# Как в классе ссылаться на элемент управления?

Tags: c#, winforms, библиотеки

Доброй ночи. Создаю свою библиотеку методов и не понимаю, как в параметр функции добавить ссылку на элемент управления? Сами элементы управления:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой первый метод с ошибкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ПАК_ИП_ОЭБ
{
    class InterfaceLibClass1
    {
        static public bool isDragging = true;
        static public void Dragging(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, string occasion, bool isDragging = true)
        {
            int oldX, oldY;
            if (occasion == "MouseDown"){                    
                oldX = e.X;
                oldY = e.Y;
            }
            else if (occasion == "MouseMove") {
                oldX = e.X;
                oldY = e.Y;
                sender.Top = sender.Top + (e.Y - oldY);
                sender.Left = sender.Left + (e.X - oldX);
            }
            else if (occasion == "MouseUp") {
                isDragging = false;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sender` - это `object`. А у `object` нет свойств. Вам нужно тип `object` отправителя привести к типу `Control`. Например:

```
if(sender is Control)
{
   var yourControl = sender as Control;
}
```

Для **C# 7.0.** можно так (комментарий от @VladD):

```
if (sender is Control yourControl) { ... }
```

Comment: В современном C# можно проще: `if (sender is Control yourControl) { ... }`.

Comment: Ошибок теперь нет. Но вот Panel, не двигается. Сейчас разберусь и отмечу как правильный ответ, если заработает). Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD, спасибо! С какой версии это появилось? Добавлю в ответ.

Comment: @Sv__t, Это C# 7.0. Можете почитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/311112/).